# Property for PXProcessing row

Tags: acumatica

I have a processing page that I want to automatically select certain types of rows.  I can set the select checkbox to true, but what property needs to be set on the row so that the process button will act on it?  Right now nothing happens unless I check another row.

```
    public void EDASNShipProj_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<EDASNShipProj.customerLocationID>(sender, "Ship Location");
        var row = (EDASNShipProj)e.Row;
        if ( row.UsrTruckNbr != 0 )
            row.Selected = true;
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<SOShipment.selected>(sender, null, true);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `PXFormula` or `PXDefault` on  `SOShipment.Selected` property with the condition you need.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after searching the base source code for ".Selected=true".  I found several places which included two extra lines.  I added them to my condition and now the checked rows are included in the process list.  Hopefully this will help others.

```
        if (row.UsrTruckNbr != 0)
        {
            row.Selected = true;
            sender.IsDirty = true;
            sender.SetStatus(row, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
        }
```